# How to update a column value for a DB function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to update a column value for a DB function?

I have a db function named by get_export(1) which has one of the columns as status and I'm trying to update status value with approved when it is awaiting

```
update get_export(1) set status='approved' where period ='awaiting'
```

which is wrong and throwing an error:

```
    ERROR:  relation "get_pdf_export" does not exist
LINE 1: update get_export set status='approved' where status='awa...
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `update` is for tables, not functions.  You have to modify the function itself.

Comment: When I do Select * from get_export, I can see different columns with values. I want to update one of the column values. how to do?

Comment: A function comes up with those values using a custom user script. Postgresql isn't as smart as a human to understand where each value comes from, and thus, you can't update values provided by a function. It's like a black box that gives you clear drinks. You can put yellow colloring in your drink, but the box will still give you clear drinks. Modify the input, or the functionality of the box, and then it will give you yellow drinks.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!